# Syntax for XPATH query in VBA code to select minimum date value

Tags: xml, vba, xpath, ms-word, xpath-1.0

I'm using Microsoft XML, v3.0 in Word VBA (Word 2016, VBA 7.1), to extract data from XML returned from a SQL Server 2008 database with a FOR XML query.

I want to extract a specific date, so I create an XPath query:

```
xpath = "//XMLPKG/CASE/EVENT[OCCURRED=0][@EVENTNO='23']/DUEDATE"
```

then run SelectNodes:

```
Set matchingNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath)
If matchingNodes.Length > 0 Then
   dueDate = matchingNodes(0).Text
End If
```

This works fine, and now I want to extract the earliest date, rather than the date from the first node. But I can't get the min() function to work. I've tried it like this:

```
xpath = "//XMLPKG/CASE/EVENT[OCCURRED=0][@EVENTNO='" & Format$(eventNum, "0") & "']/min(DUEDATE)"
```

and this:

```
xpath = "min(//XMLPKG/CASE/EVENT[OCCURRED=0][@EVENTNO='" & Format$(eventNum, "0") & "']/DUEDATE)"
```

but both forms give me an "Unknown method" error pointing to the min() function.

This is a (sanitised) version of my XML:

```
<XMLPKG>
    <CASE CASEID="1">
        <EVENT EVENTNO="23">
            <CYCLE>1</CYCLE>
            <DUEDATE>1964-11-04</DUEDATE>
            <OCCURRED>0</OCCURRED>
        </EVENT>
        <EVENT EVENTNO="23">
            <CYCLE>1</CYCLE>
            <DUEDATE>1959-11-04</DUEDATE>
            <OCCURRED>0</OCCURRED>
        </EVENT>
        <EVENT EVENTNO="23">
            <CYCLE>1</CYCLE>
            <EVENTDATE>1954-05-11</EVENTDATE>
            <OCCURRED>1</OCCURRED>
        </EVENT>
        <EVENT EVENTNO="124">
            <CYCLE>1</CYCLE>
            <EVENTDATE>1960-07-01</EVENTDATE>
            <OCCURRED>1</OCCURRED>
        </EVENT>
    </CASE>
</XMLPKG>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min()` function is not available in XPath 1.0, which is the XPath version that MSXML provides.

> I want to extract the earliest date

This is not possible in XPath 1.0, which can only compare things that can successfully be converted to numbers. For example, finding out the EVENT with the smallest @EVENTNO would work like this:

```
//EVENT[not(@EVENTNO > //EVENT/@EVENTNO)]
```

For target values that are arbitrary strings, it would be necessary that strings can be compared to each other lexicographically, which would require collation knowledge, and that is not available in XPath 1.0.

But since VBA can compare strings, I would use something like this:

```vb
Dim eventDate As Variant, smallestDate As String

For Each eventDate In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//EVENT[OCCURRED=0]/EVENTDATE")
   If smallestDate = "" Or eventDate.text < smallestDate Then smallestDate = eventDate.text
Next

MsgBox "Earliest event: " & smallestDate
```